# Accessing Video in XCode-simulator fails

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uivideoeditorcontroller

I use XCode 9.1 and the iPhone 6 Plus Simulator. Language is Objective-C.

I let the user select a video from the camera roll and store it to the users's directory within the app for further processing.

Now, I want to edit that video using `UIVideoEditorController`. But the Flag for `canEditVideoAtPath` returns false.

It's a regular .MOV File...

[Edit]

I was completely on the wrong track when I first asked this question...

[Edit 2]

And now I feel stupid because `UIVideoEditorController` doesn't work on the simulator because it doesn't have a camera... duh...